# Toiletries in hand bag while travelling

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

So far i have been travelling with checked in luggage but now i am planning to avoid it and travel with just hand baggage. 
I generally carry Toiletries like Shampoo, shaving cream, toothpaste [all packs are less than 100ml or gm] and also shaving razor [Gillette Mach 3] and a scissor. 
Will all this stuff be allowed in hand luggage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a regular traveller this is exactly how to travel. All of the things you mention are allowed, at least, usually.

There are very few places now that totally disallow liquids, and indeed, several countries don't consider liquids in any quantity a security threat at all.

For the other countries that do impose restrictions on liquids, I suggest you keep all your liquid toiletries in a transparent bag that's immediately accessible. That way, when you travel through an airport that requires a liquid inspection, you can pull all your toiletries out with no hassle at the security. If anyone wants to take a closer look at your liquids, they are all in the bag separately on the tray. This also means if your bag is flagged for inspection because of liquids, it can be resolved much quicker. Please do not be one of those people who has to unpack everything at security, it is exceptionally annoying. :)

I've never had a problem with disposable razors, but scissors sometimes arouse interest, and I've had a few of pairs confiscated in my time. The blades, measured from the pivot point, should generally be shorter than 5 cm, but this varies globally. Some places like liquids but hate scissors: Australia is particularly picky, and insists that the scissor blades have rounded ends, I think I've lost more than one pair to Australian security. Since I bought a proper pair of travel scissors, no one has minded, although I have been asked to produce them for inspection on occasion.

Comment: This echoes my scissors experience exactly. Even worse than losing the short-bladed surgical scissors I'd carried for decades to a teenaged security officer in Panama was the sneer that accompanied the confiscation. Sigh.

Comment: Note that in most places the transparent bag is a hard requirement, not a convenience, and it must not be larger than one liter. Scissors depend on the country - I never had problems in Europe, but apparently Hong Kong disallows any scissors (I assume that we’re talking nail scissors, larger one will rarely be allowed). However, they are also cheap and easily replaced.

Comment: Thank You for your input. Also based on above discussion i believe Nail cutters should be allowed ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer will vary, depending upon where you're boarding and where you're going.

In the US, or flying to the US, TSA has [this to say](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule) about carry-on liquids:

> You are allowed to bring a quart-sized bag of liquids, aerosols, gels, creams and pastes in your carry-on bag and through the checkpoint. These are limited to travel-sized containers that are 3.4 ounces (100 milliliters) or less per item. Placing these items in the small bag and separating from your carry-on baggage facilitates the screening process. Pack items that are in containers larger than 3.4 ounces or 100 milliliters in checked baggage.
>
> Any liquid, aerosol, gel, cream or paste that alarms during screening will require additional screening.

As to shaving razors, the same page says:

> **Disposable Razor**
>
> Carry On Bags: Yes
>
> Checked Bags: Yes
>
> Any sharp objects in checked bags should be sheathed or securely wrapped to prevent injury to baggage handlers and inspectors.

I've carried disposable razors (one or two at a time) in my bathroom kit within my carry-on daypack, for years without difficulty or questions.

Note that in all cases, the TSA page warns:

> The final decision rests with the TSA officer on whether an item is allowed through the checkpoint.

Comment: Most (or all) European airports have similar rules, with 100 ml and one liter as sizes.

Comment: In UK, the bag is supposed to be transparent to allow a visual check.

Comment: I think the bag has to be transparent in all countries, and easy to re-close.